# Need help trying to return sydney time using eastern time

Tags: sql-server

I have a function in MSSQL that returns sydney time, however when i check it with the local sydney time I have 2-3 minutes difference. For example if the local time in sydney is 7:24:00, my time is 7:26:28. My function is shown below.I checked it with timeanddate.com. Could the difference in time be caused by the server synchronization or am i doing something wrong?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetInOutDaylightAU](@date datetime)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
       DECLARE @year int = DATEPART(year, @date)

       DECLARE @dateStartDaylight datetime
       DECLARE @dataEndDaylight datetime

       SET @dateStartDaylight = CAST(CAST(@year AS nvarchar) + '-10-'+ CAST((7 - (floor(@year * 5 / 4) + 5) % 7) AS nvarchar)+' 00:00:00' AS datetime)
       SET @dataEndDaylight = CAST(CAST(@year AS nvarchar) + '-04-'+ CAST((7 - (floor(@year * 5 / 4) + 4) % 7) AS nvarchar)+' 00:00:00' AS datetime)

       DECLARE @changeVal int

       SET @changeVal = CASE WHEN @date BETWEEN @dataEndDaylight AND @dateStartDaylight THEN 1 ELSE -1 END

       set @date = DATEADD(HOUR, @changeVal, @date)   
       set @date = DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @date)     
       RETURN @date --DATEADD(HOUR, @changeVal, @date)
END
GO
```

Comment: I guess it is the time synchronization between the servers I am using

Comment: Go to a global clock page.  Are the times correct on both the client computer in AU and USA?  If not, correct your time.

Comment: This just sounds to me like you are checking SQL Server's time against your watch or your local workstation or something. If so, you need to make sure you sync all the things against the same time server. I bet my workstation is a minute or two off from your SQL Server, too...